# vimtex: configure to indent '[ ... ]' and '\[ ... \]' blocks

Tags: indentation, plugin-vimtex

When setting indentation using `vimtex`, I meet some problem.
I set the option `g:vimtex_indent_delims` to indent `[...]` blocks.

```
let g:vimtex_indent_delims = {
      \ 'open'  : ['{','(','['],
      \ 'close' : ['}',')',']'],
      \}
```

But then the `\[...\]` block will indent twice.
What I get is the following.

```
\[
        f(x)
\]
[
    f(x)
]
```

Compared with this, there is no problem for `{...}` and `\{...\}` blocks,
or `(...)` and `\(...\)` blocks.

```
\{
    f(x)
\}
{
    f(x)
}
\(
    f(x)
\)
(
    f(x)
)
```

So, is it possible to indent `[...]` blocks, while indent `\[...\]` blocks only one time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify regexes that do not match on `\[` and `\]`. This should work:

```
let g:vimtex_indent_delims = {
      \ 'open'  : ['{', '(', vimtex#re#not_bslash . '['],
      \ 'close' : ['}', ')', vimtex#re#not_bslash . ']'],
      \}
```

The `vimtex#re#bslash` is a regex that matches whenever the preceding atom is *not* a single backslash.